# multiple docker push of same image with different tag is giving blob upload unknown

Tags: docker, nexus

there is an image called "abcd" and I have tagged the image as tag1, tag2 and tag3.

now I would like to push the tags together tag1, tag2 and tag3 but one of the docker push is resulting in blob upload unknown and not updating our nexus repository.

other tag has been uploaded ok. only any one of the tag fails

```
1f82d3184114: Pushed
6e4167fbb03e: Pushed
d4be35236dd2: Pushed
8e63fc7f2cbf: Pushed
b9e7300e2ec2: Pushed
c9b8c8ae2269: Pushed
0edf0726786a: Pushed
6d2e8fa5dc28: Pushed
50644c29ef5a: Layer already exists
blob upload unknown
```

some people face similar issue I saw but no proper solution

docker client version 19.03.12

Comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2225

Comment: seems like its too complicated.. whats simple fix ?

Comment: How does the reverse proxy of your nexus-repo look like?

Comment: Looks like there is some misconfiguration in the proxy. Can you post docker-engine logs & verify the proxy settings???

Comment: Are your running an up-to-date version of nexus repository ?